# Code syntax explaination help

Tags: c#

I am learning WPF and there's a piece of code which I don't quite understand the method declared with constraints:

```
public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    where T : class // Need help to interpret this method declaration
```

I understand this is a shared method and T has be a class but what is what is 'static T FindAncestor'? Having troubles interpreting it as a whole. Thanks!

**Code:**

```
public static class VisualTreeHelperExtensions
{
    public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        where T : class // Need help to interpret this method
    {
        DependencyObject target = dependencyObject;
        do
        {
            target = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(target);
        }
        while (target != null && !(target is T));
        return target as T;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `static` keyword in front means that you do not have to instantiate `VisualTreeHelperExtensions` in order to call the `FindAncestor` method.  You can say:

```
VisualTreeHelperExtensions.FindAncestor<MyClass>(myObj);
```

Where `myObj` is a `DependencyObject`.  The `where`, as you said, makes sure that `T` (`MyClass` in this case) is indeed a class

For convenience, Methods like this can be declared like this:

```
public static T FindAncestor<T>(this DependencyObject dependencyObject)
  where T : class // Need help to interpret this method declaration
```

Which would allow you to call the method like so:

```
myObj.FindAncestor<MyClass>();
```

Effectively adding a method to your `DependencyObject` after the fact.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The `T` is a placeholder for a type - what is known as a generic. The `where` clause is a generic constraint that requires reference types.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understand your question.

It's a declaration of public static function.

If it's not you're asking for, please explain better.

Answer (score 1):

It means that it is a static method (you can call it without an instance of the class created) that returns an object of type T. `FindAncestor` is the name of the method.